# Microsoft ClickOnce and some sort of redirect problem

Tags: networking, clickonce

I am attempting to debug a client issue with our ClickOnce application. He is the only person with this particular deployment problem.

> A connection attempt failed because
>   the connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond
>   192.168.0.1:80

The message is straightforward enough, but I am out of ideas for debugging. I have tried the following

- Had user ping our deployment server and it comes back with proper ip address
- User's local network is of 192.168.1.x format and not 192.168.0.x. Pinging the error message ip address gives not found error
- Had user disable VPN, Firewall and A/V
- Interestingly if he uninstalls our software and then visits our ClickOnce page our program is actually downloaded and installed. But then when it tries to launch he gets the error
- Installed Fiddler and I can see that when the program launches he sends out an initial request and gets a 200 response, but then the program fails with above message.
- Another computer on same network works fine. Had user switch ports on the switch.

Thank you for any additional troubleshooting tips. I just can't figure out where this ip address is coming from and why they are encountering it. User is very technologically adept so I can ask him to do complicated things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the client install Wireshark or Microsoft Network Monitor on his computer and start a capture and then run your program. Have him save the capture and send it to you. Look at the capture and look for anything unusual like an ICMP redirect when your program attempts the connection.

Also, compare his routing table to a working clients (on the same network) routing table and run a tracert from his machine and a working machine to the "endpoint" that your program connects to. Also check for any proxies that may be redirecting HTTP traffic.

Comment: I did install both these apps, but so much data is generated and I don't have enough networking knowledge to sort through the results.